# How to find all the positive integer number $n$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}=0$ and $|a_{i}|=1$ has a solution in $\mathbb{C}$ with $a_i+a_j\neq 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, number-theory

> Find all the $n$ for which there exist complex numbers $a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n}$ such that:
>
> (1):$$|a_{i}|=1,i=1,2,\cdots,n$$
> (2):$$a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n}=0$$
> (3): for any $i\neq j$,have
> $$a_{i}+a_{j}\neq 0$$

My idea: maybe Considering the unit circle Uniform point?  But I can't find it.Thank you

Comment: $n=3$ is one solution.

Comment: I think $n\ge3$?

Comment: when $n$ is odd, you can take $a_k=e^{2\pi i\frac{k-1}{n}}$

Comment: When $n$ has an odd divisor $d$, you can take the example for $n=d$ and use it $n/d$ times to get an example for $n$. So all $n$ that have an odd divisor work; the remaining cases are $n=2^k$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy,you mean this problem for all $n$ is such condition?

Comment: $n=4$ is not a solution ; this follows from the fact that two distinct circles intersect in at mots $2$ points. If $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4=0$ and $w=a_1+a_2=(-a_3)+(-a_4)$, consider the circles with centers $0$ or $w$ and radius $1$

Comment: maybe I guess $n\neq 2^k?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true for $ n\neq 1, 2, 4$.

The case $n=1, 2$ are obvious.

The case $n=4$ is [a standard question](https://brilliant.org/discussions/thread/system-of-complex-equations/) (as pointed out by Ewan). In the note, you will also see a discussion of solution sets which satisfy your conditions (1) and (2) for more general $n$. In particular, there isn't much that we can conclude for $n\geq 5$.

The construction for $n$ odd is given by an $n-$sided regular polygon.

The construction for $n = 2k, k \geq 3$ is given by taking a $2k-3$ sided regular polygon and an equilateral triangle (suitably rotated to avoid diameters).